# How to set a default selected option when generating a list with ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm generating a  with *ngFor which doesn't allow me to directly set a "selected" attribute, what is the correct way to do that? I would like the last option to be selected but it doesn't really matter.

```
<select>
  <option
    *ngFor="let searchType of dateSearchTypeGroup"
    [ngValue]="searchType"
    (click)="onSelect(searchType)"
  >
    {{ searchType.viewValue }}
  </option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:**
thank you for your answers but nothing made it. Iv'e found another solution: as the list i'm iterating on to generate the dropdown list is defined as an array i just set the selected value to the first row of the array:

```
dateSearchTypeGroup;
  selectedSearchType: DateSearchType;

  constructor() {
    this.dateSearchTypeGroup = dateSearchTypeGroup;
    this.selectedSearchType = this.dateSearchTypeGroup[0];
  }
```

And it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

if default value is on the basis of index or it is pre defined.

```
<select>
  <option
    *ngFor="let searchType of dateSearchTypeGroup; #i = index"
    [ngValue]="searchType"
    [selected]="i == 0"
    (click)="onSelect(searchType)">
    {{ searchType.viewValue }}
  </option>
</select>
```

if your default value is based upon some logic then

**HTML**

```
  <select>
      <option
        *ngFor="let searchType of dateSearchTypeGroup; #i = index"
        [ngValue]="searchType"
        [selected]="searchType === defaultValue"
        (click)="onSelect(searchType)">
        {{ searchType.viewValue }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

**JS/Typescript**

```
// *let assume your array is like this.*

dateSearchTypeGroup = [41, 42, 47, 48];

// *your logic or api call here*

defaultValue = 47;
```

you can also use ngModel on select tag.

Answer (score 1):

```js
public searchTypeModel;
...
ngOnInit() {
   this.searchTypeModel = this.dateSearchTypeGroup[this.dateSearchTypeGroup.length - 1];
}
```

```html
<select [ngModel]="searchTypeModel">
  <option
    *ngFor="let searchType of dateSearchTypeGroup"
    [ngValue]="searchType"
    (click)="onSelect(searchType)"
  >
    {{ searchType.viewValue }}
  </option>
</select>
```